# Kibana visualization showing wrong results when compared to discover

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, sense

I am using kibana for visualization on elastic search. I am trying to find the maximum occurring terms in cleaned_keyword_phrases, which is an array of keywords. Basically the cleaned keyword_phrases is an array of skills eg: ["java","spring","ms word"].

The results that I get when I am searching for a query(primary_class:"job" and jobPost:"java developer") is showing correct results when I see it in discover tab, but in visualize tab the results are wrong.

Eg, when i am searching for java developer, these are the results being displayed(these seem right) in quick count in result:

discover result:

[image]

Whereas when i try to visualize, the results change(these seem wrong) and are displayed as:

visualize results:

[image]

Infact, on changing query to developer from "java developer" the results in quick count in discover change but the results in the visualization tab remain the same. This makes me feel that the query is not being run in visualize tab.

I tried running the query using sense plugin but in that too the results are coming wrong.

Query:

```
 {
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "primary_class:\"job\" and jobPost:\"java developer\"",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cleaned_keyword_phrases",
        "size": 20,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

kibana Version  4.0.2
Build   6004
Commit SHA  b286116

Edit: Good results are results which are more related to the query i.e. java developer in this context. Thus results coming up in quick count on the discover tab are "Good" and the ones showing up in the visualize tab seem bad as they are not related(these are not changing when changing the command in kibana).

Comment: Please be more specific about what is wrong, I mean what is the 'good' result you wish to achieve in visualize tab?

Comment: Good result is the one showing up in the first image i.e. quick counts coming in the discover tab. i.e. more related to "java developer", which is in the command run on kibana.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my hostnames, similar to yours.
The visualization splits a name like vm-xx-yy in vm, xx and yy and show the results for that.
After setting the field from index:analyzed to index:not_analyzed it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your visualisation when attached on a dashboards with same query string in search bar ? If it does apply query string on when on dashboard then may be because here on visualize we are just creating a visualization !